# Python custom text to html syntax

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a custom syntax for my users to format some html

so a user can enter something like:

```
**some text here**
the some more text down here
**Another bunch of stuff**
then some other junk

and I get:

<h1>some text here</h2>
<p>the some more text down here</p>
<h1>Another bunch of stuff</h1>
<p>then some other junk</p>
```

and hopefully leave some room to make up other tags as I need them

edit:
So my question is how would I write the regex function to convert some given text and have it find every instance of an opening and closing ** and replace them with the appropriate  or  tags.
i have:
import re

header_pattern = re.compile(r'(?P**)(?P.*)(?P**)', re.MULTILINE)

```
def format_headers(text):
    def process_match(m):
        return "<h2>%s</h2>" % m.group('header')

    new_text = header_pattern.sub(process_match, text)

    print new_text
```

but this only grabs the first ** and last ** and ignores ones in the middle.

Comment: Why not use existing markdown solutions? Also, what is actually your question?

Comment: Markdown is pretty standard, so unless you absolutely *must* have `**text**` transform into `<h1>text</h2>`, I'd recommend using it. And, of course, libraries exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use some standard  solution. Like Markdown**. Its is most preferable.

To match your header strings use `r'\*\*(.*?)\*\*'`. See example

```
>>> re.sub(r'\*\*(.*?)\*\*','<h1>\\1</h1>', '**some text here** and **another**')
'<h1>some text here</h1> and <h1>another</h1>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you couldn't use a simple template language like Cheetah and build the logic into even handlers? Cheetah would allow you to create a template objects that contain a set of methods useful for manipulating HTML. 
  I had a similar issue a few weeks back when I was trying to use CherryPy to create a webpage, in the tutorials I found Cheetah templates and it made writing the forms so much easier!